# Assert module use in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello everyone I was reading node official documentation, and I've seen the "Assert" module, but don't understand its use, my conclutions up to now are that is like the (try--catch) of some languages, the examples on official documentation are not enough for me to understand the module, could you guys help me please?

Comment: It's a tool for unit testing.  It's not something I would throw into a regular application, but there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

Comment: Hello brad thank you, could you say a pseudo-code example in where "Assert module" could be used?

Comment: There are some examples here:  http://cjohansen.no/en/node_js/unit_testing_node_js_apps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These would be used for unit testing.

> This module is used for writing unit tests for your applications, you can access it with require('assert').
>   http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

The goal of a unit test is to test individual units of your code. 
For example, to test a function, you give it the input and know what output to expect. This will isolate that function so you can be sure there is not an error in other parts of your code.

Comment: Haha, oh yes, I came by that page, But I cannot understand what is the goal of a "Unit test" could you give some reference of its means

Comment: That page says "The node:assert module provides a set of assertion functions for verifying invariants." and looking at the history in https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4532 suggests that assert is not actually meant to be used in unit tests.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Node assert documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html):

> The assert module provides a simple set of assertion tests that can be used to test invariants. The module is intended for internal use by Node.js, but can be used in application code via require('assert'). However, assert is not a testing framework, and is not intended to be used as a general purpose assertion library.

A simple use of the `assert` module would be to prevent a division by zero:

```
var noDivZero = (dividend, divisor) => {
  try {
    assert(divisor !== 0, 'DivisionByZeroException')
    return dividend / divisor
  } catch(e) {
    return e.message
  }
}

noDivZero(10, 0); // DivisionByZeroException
```